# Recommendations on how to decouple services (RSS, REST API) from my UI (webforms) when they share a common model?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, encapsulation

I have a web application that is arranged into data, business and UI projects. As the system evolves changes are deployed by building all three projects and deploying them in one package. This has worked well and has allowed the illusion of “three tiers” without tackling the communications, versioning issues of truly separate systems.

So along comes a request for XML summaries of some of the data and my thoughts turn to a fancy WCF service that, one day, could be my “Web API” (ahh… the mind.. what a evil little monkey it is). So, assuming this survives the “is that really the best idea?” test here is my question:

> > What structure have you had the most success with when posed with two 
> >     evolving “clients” serving content from a single evolving “model”?

Answer (score 0):

James, your question is rather board as there are a large number of variables that go into choosing the right type of architecture for your needs. I would recommend reading the [patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide) to better understand the options and pick the best one that suits your individual needs.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is broad but I'm hoping to find individual experiences with specific approaches that turned out well.

I definitely will read through that guide but I'm wary of getting abstract guidance or hand-chosen test cases. Sort of like if you want to select an ORM, there are a many individual reviews available. When it comes to the business logic tier in the .NET world, it's seems much harder to find descriptions of real world use.

I appreciate the guidance though, thanks!